# How can I display an Image throbber in XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, throbber

I have tried to show a Throbber in XE7 but its not working.

I Generated several Images in several generation pages, now how can't get it to move.

For now I need to use this in the VCL platform.

Those any one done this already.

Thanks.

Comment: VCL or FireMonkey?  If FireMonkey which platform?

Comment: A 'throbber' as in an animated image? Try TGifImage, or otherwise try cycling through which images are painted via a timer.